# Why can't I move this value into this memory address?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to move a value into a specific memory address. The value is defined in an external file as a set of WORDs, 16 bits on my system.

```
mov [0xb8000], [OperatingSystemBootText]
```

However, when I try to compile the code, the system says that I have an invalid combination of operators and operands. I've tried defining the memory address as a variable before placing it inside a bracket but that didn't work. I don't understand why this doesn't work.
Thank you to the community member who suggested a similar question. It helped me solve the issue.

Comment: You can't move memory to memory with the `mov` instruction. You have to move the value from memory to a register and then move from the register to memory. Otherwise you'd have to use something like [movsw](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq)